# getting error on ionic emulate?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am new to Mac and Ionic. Creating my first ionic application is not working for me. Getting this error on **ionic emulate ios**

```
    An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/{USER}/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/AD8136DB-9E63-4298-918D-561520165B83/system.log'
```

Comment: Try updating XCode and make sure the iphone emulator runs without ionic.

Comment: @Orane still getting the same exception.